# Apply sorting algorithm to database query

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I want to make another list with "What's Hot" like [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/).

I [found this topic](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) where it explains how their sorting algorithm works

First I want to ask, if it is legal to use their algorithm?

And if yes, how would I apply it to PHP database query.
Do I need to SELECT all posts first and then sort it?

```
function hot($ups, $downs, $date) {
    $s = $ups - $downs;
    $order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10);
    if(s > 0) {
        $sign = 1;
    } elseif(s < 0) {
        $sign = -1;
    } else {
        $sign = 0;
    }
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $seconds = $date->format('U');
    return round($order + $sign * $seconds / 45000, 7);
}
```

this is what I get when I convert it to PHP.

Comment: An algorithm can't be copyrighted, only the implementation of an algorithm... so it shouldn't be illegal

Comment: Yes, since algorithms can be recreated from engineering first principles, it should be hard to copyright them. That said, there are some compression and video formats for which the algorithm itself is commercial property, so it's a difficult point to answer categorically. That said, in _most_ cases I would just say to go ahead.

Comment: It's almost certainly also going to be more efficient to implement in the ORDER BY clause of your SQL query rather than in your PHP code

Comment: If you are able know the algorithm via well known website than it is surely not copyrighted. Use it freely with your implementation. But if u r lifting someone else's implementation then it might be illegal

Comment: what about SQL, @MarkBaker is it possible to implement something like this in ORDER BY clause>?

Comment: I have seen many SQL queries (not an expert :) ) but nothing that looked like this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues and not showing attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ups and downs columns are called `ups` and `downs`, then something like:

```
ORDER BY ROUND(
    ( LOG10(
          GREATEST(
              ABS(`ups` - `downs`), 
              1
          )
      ) + 
      SIGN(`ups` - `downs`) *
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_posted`)  / 45000
    ),
    7
)
```

It might be a better idea to use this formula to create a calculated column in your select list, and then order by that column

**EDIT**

Example of a calculated column:

```
SELECT `ups`,
       `downs`,
       `posted_date`,
       ROUND(
           ( LOG10(
               GREATEST(
                   ABS(`ups` - `downs`), 
                   1
               )
             ) + 
             SIGN(`ups` - `downs`) *
             UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_posted`)  / 45000
           ),
           7
       ) AS hotness
  FROM `posts`
```

So `hotness` is your calculated column

Comment: WoW, thanks, thats really amazing, I think I need to digg into mySQL. but I don't see where you use date, I undestand UNIX_TIMESTAMP, but original algorithm is depended on date the post was created, no?

Comment: Added post date, assuming that the column name is `date_posted`

Comment: I will read about it, I never heared of calculated column and I find nothing online. Do you mean something like VIEW?